# Saving ListView data with Yes / No Message Box

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have used 100% of the code presented as a solution here (and which I am extremely grateful for), but still hitting a wall.  The problems is I still cant save the file with the file name I choose (see InputBox), this is because its not the same as rtb further down the code. How do I combine the two?

Code

Dim fileSaved As Boolean

```
Do Until fileSaved
    Dim saveFile As String = InputBox("Enter a file name to save this message")
    If saveFile = "" Then Exit Sub
    Dim docs As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
    Dim filePath As String = IO.Path.Combine(docs, "Visual Studio 2013\Projects", saveFile & ".txt")

        fileSaved = True
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(filePath) Then
            Dim msg As String = "File Already Exists. Do You Wish To Overwrite it?"
            Dim style As MsgBoxStyle = MsgBoxStyle.YesNo Or MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton2 Or MsgBoxStyle.Critical
            fileSaved = (MsgBox(msg, style, "Warning") = MsgBoxResult.Yes)
        End If
    Loop

    'THIS CODE save content to Test.txt NOT saveFile as desired
    Dim rtb As New RichTextBox
    rtb.AppendText("Generation, Num Of Juveniles, Num of Adults, Num of Semiles, Total" & vbNewLine)
    For Each saveitem As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        rtb.AppendText(
                       saveitem.Text & ", " &
                       saveitem.SubItems(1).Text & ", " &
                       saveitem.SubItems(2).Text & ", " &
                       saveitem.SubItems(3).Text & ", " &
                       saveitem.SubItems(4).Text & vbNewLine)
    Next
    rtb.SaveFile("C:\Users\RICHARD\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Test.txt", _
    RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
```

Comment: PS I also appreciate that there is a lot of code bloat here with the for each loop - I guess this should be a function but I;m still working on that

Comment: Dont try to do all three things in one giant procedure.  When they click, invoke a function which does bullet 1; if all is well, invoke a method to do #2 etc.  [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Comment: @Plutonix Agreed, I should break this down into functions.  I think this might help me go back to the option of entering a new file name if the user does not wish to overwrite the file.  However, how do I combine the variable Save File with my rtb??

Comment: Put the code (starting with the `InputBox` statement in a loop. Set a Boolean value to indicate if the data has been saved. Continue the loop until the data has been saved.

Comment: A `SaveFileDialog` would allow you to get rid of all those MSGBOX things, assure a valid path location and could include the overwrite prompt.

Comment: @Blackwood Thank you. Mmm, the code feels like it needs a loop. Trying to think of what kind (not a for) perhaps do until? Its a good suggestion but it will take me time to work  out this loop

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, it would. I have to stick to a brief however to develop my understanding - so cant really pursue you no mess suggestion :( Will definitely think functions but it will take me time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code loops until a Boolean variable is set to indicate that the data was saved.

```
Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim fileSaved As Boolean 
    Do Until fileSaved 
        Dim saveFile As String = InputBox("Enter a file name to save this message")
        If saveFile = "" Then Exit Sub
        Dim docs As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments 
        Dim filePath As String = IO.Path.Combine(docs, "Visual Studio 2013\Projects", saveFile & ".txt")

        fileSaved = True
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(filePath) Then
            Dim msg As String = "File Already Exists. Do You Wish To Overwrite it?"
            Dim style As MsgBoxStyle = MsgBoxStyle.YesNo Or MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton2 Or MsgBoxStyle.Critical
            fileSaved = (MsgBox(msg, style, "Warning") = MsgBoxResult.Yes) 
        End If
    Loop

    'your code to save the data goes here
    'the filePath String contains the path you want to save the file to.
End Sub
```

[Edit] Correct logic and created a filePath variable to store the path to the file. Also added code to allow the user to exit by entering an empty string.

Comment: Massive, massive thanks. I'm trying to implement this now and real figure out how it all works. I wish I could repay your kindness in helping me to learn

Comment: Mmm, this code is generating errors, which I'm working on - because I'm a million times better off then I was when I started. I think the problem is two-fold. A)  if the file is not found, it shows 'file exists' dialogue box B) The file wont save with the name I give it, because my code will only save the data as 'Test'. This problem is because I don't know how to make savefile = to rtb (see original post)

Comment: @Student my apologies. I had the logic the wrong way round when checking if the file exists. I have corrected that. I added code to store the path to the file in a variable that you can use in your code to save the data. I also added code to give the user a way to quit (by entering an empty string in the `InputBox`.

Comment: Ahh..sorry - thank you so much Blackwood. Will implement and study suggestions. To be honest, your early suggestion was very good exercise for me!

Comment: @Student, if this works, you should very kindly take the time to click the checkmark next to the answer.  It will remove this from the Unanswered list, show others searching for similar answers that this works and show that you participate in the process.